# Insert number of rows based on cell value change

Tags: vba, excel

I really cannot figure this out. Could someone help please?

I have two sheets (sheet 1, and sheet 2).
There is one column in sheet 1 records all team size - how many people in the team. The team size can be changed by team manager. For example, yesterday team 1 can have a team size of 5 and team manager changes the team size to 7 today.

What I need to do by using VBA is to insert number of rows in sheet 2 based on the value change in team size column. Use the example above, because team 1 size (say cell E10 in sheet 1) changed from 5 to 7, two rows will be insert at the bottom of sheet 2 (7-5=2).

I hope it makes sense and I really appreciate any help! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. Just put this code in `Sheet1` module:

```
Dim oldValue As String
'saving old value
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   oldValue = Target.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   'if changing cell in third column
   If Target.Column = 3 Then
      'suppose teamname store in the same row as num of players and in column #2
      teamName = Sheet1.Cells(Target.Row, 2)

      'determining lastrow in sheet2
      lastrow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

      'insetr changing log
      Sheet2.Range("A" & lastrow + 1) = teamName & ": old value " & oldValue
      Sheet2.Range("A" & lastrow + 2) = teamName & ": new value " & Target.Value
   End If
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Hope it helps